# Vlookup, excel, error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following code:

- It is supposed to go into a sheet named "Flash" and get the i-th 2 digit numeric value and retrieve the value in a column offset 4 to the right of the Activecell.
- Then swap to a sheet named "Sheet1" on the same workbook and use a Vertical Lookup function to find the retrieved value and return the value 4 columns to the right of that cell.

However when i run the script below it stops working at :

`MsgBox (ActiveSheet.VLookup(LookFor, "A:A", 4, True))`

and VBA throws `error 438 object doesn't support this property or method`

does anyone know why there's an exception?

```
' Begin lookup :
Dim i As Integer, designator As String, LookFor As String
Flash.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Select
For i = 3 To lastUsedCellInRow("C")
    designator = "C" + CStr(i)
    Dim cellVal As String
    cellVal = ActiveSheet.Range(designator).Value()
    If (Len(cellVal) <= 2 And IsNumeric(cellVal)) Then
        LookFor = ActiveSheet.Range(designator).Offset(0, 4).Value()
        RawData.Activate
        MsgBox (ActiveSheet.VLookup(LookFor, "A:A", 4, True))
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: `activesheet.worksheetfunction.vlookup`

Comment: @TomIngram hmm...that sounds like it could work but when i replaced my method with that it still returns the `438` error...

Comment: Try `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several issues

1. You need to refer to the range as `Range("A:A")` not `"A:A"`
2. If you are using `VLOOKUP` rather than `LOOKUP` then as stated you need to be referring to a four column range , `Range("A:D")`
3. You need to handle your test value not being found in A

Sample code below for you to adapt

```
Dim strLookfor as String
Dim strOut
strLookfor = "test"
strOut = Application.VLookup(strLookfor, Range("A:D"), 4, True)
If IsError(strOut) Then
    MsgBox "value not found"
Else
'return column D value as string
    MsgBox CStr(strOut)
End If
```

**Follow-up**

Yes, you could use

```
`strOut = Application.VLookup(strLookfor & "*", Range("A:D"), 4, True)`
```

for this match

bu I think `Find` is cleaner, ie

```
Dim strLookfor As String
strLookfor = "F71"
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(strfolder & "*", , xlValues, xlPart)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Match in " & rng1.Offset(0, 3)
Else
    MsgBox strfolder & "*" & vbNewLine & "not found"
End If
```

Comment: Just as a follow up, will Vlookup accurately match a search for "F71" to a data point containing the string "F71 - More Nonsense Follows" ?

Comment: ended up just using a for loop Mid() and and Len() functions to find the terms i was looking for. will try this method though. thanks a lot @brettdj